# How to effectively set up MySQL Users and Roles in the production server WITHOUT Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, configuration, membership-provider, production-environment, roleprovider

So far I have been using the WebSite Administration Tool built in Visual Studio 2010 to manage Users and Roles along with MySQL Membership and Roles Provider.

Now, I have deployed the application to the production server and I am getting the following error:

[image]

Even if I tried to copy one of the roles and one of the users from my local DB to the one used by the production server, it didn't quite work and I keep getting the same error. At least, I'm sure that's the cause of the error because I did a remote debugging which led me to find it.

At this point I am very confused on how to get it working properly. So, any help or guidance would be really appreciated.

**EDIT:** At this point the User has been already authenticated in the login page using the connectionString to the production DB server. For that reason, I have dismissed any kind of problems related to the connectionString. I get this error while loading the masterPage where the role is needed in order to choose which menu to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this problem was to create the mysql_aspnet_membership provider by granting full access through the machine.config and autogenerating the schema, instead of manually creating the membership tables in the database, which I though there could have been a valid way to create the db.

Afterwards, this didn't break anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The exception message says it all: It cannot connect to the database. Verify that your production DB server is running, that the connection string is correct and that you have network connectivity (including name resolution) from the web server to the DB server.

Comment: At this point the User has been already authenticated in the login page using the connectionString to the production DB server. For that reason, I have dismissed any kind of problems related to the connectionString. I get this error while loading the masterPage where the role is needed to choose which menu to display. Any other idea? Thanks for your help